# Cannot find Objective-C pod on Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have this pod on my project:

**Podfile:**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'Parse'
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
pod 'MagicalRecord'
pod 'Socket.IO-Client-Swift'
pod 'SDWebImage'
pod 'MBProgressHUD'
pod 'HexColors'
pod 'SWTableViewCell'
pod 'AKPickerView'
pod 'CRToast'
pod 'MTDates'
pod 'JazzHands'
```

**Project-Bridging-Header**

```
#import <JazzHands/IFTTTJazzHands.h>
#import <MTDates/NSDate+MTDates.h>
#import <MTDates/NSDateComponents+MTDates.h>
```

I can use any MTDates function at any Objective-C or Swift file.
And I can use any JazzHands function/class at any Objective-C file, but when I try to use it on Swift like this:

```
import UIKit
class GICalendarViewController: UIViewController{
    var separatorFrameAnimation: IFTTTFrameAnimation!
```

I've got this error:

> Use of undeclared type 'IFTTTFrameAnimation'

I've tried to add @objc tag on this class, and this doesn't work.

Any ideas why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use these libraries as frameworks (`use_frameworks!`). So you have to add

```
import JazzHands
```

in your source files. The same you do with Cocoa's frameworks like UIKit.

Comment: Oh, any idea why MTDates doesn't need it?